# Can we use Admob reward ads without giving any rewards to user?

Tags: android, ads, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I wanted to ask is it legal to use the Google Admob reward ads without giving any reward to the user like coins, points or etc. And can we use these ads in non-gaming applications like maps applications or chatting applications and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The video type of interstitial ads rather than the rewarded video ads should suit your purpose. Try using the sample unit id for the interstitial video written in [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads) to see if it is really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is legal and feasible. Rewarded ads are commonly used to continue playing with same items, weapons, collectables... after your character dies instead of losing all the progress. And AdMob is not limited to games.